# How to filter wikidata labels in concept search?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I am using the following code to get the `wikidata labels` for the given concept (e.g., `network analysis`).

```
SELECT ?item {
    VALUES ?searchTerm { "network analysis" }
    SERVICE wikibase:mwapi {
        bd:serviceParam wikibase:api "EntitySearch".
        bd:serviceParam wikibase:endpoint "www.wikidata.org".
        bd:serviceParam wikibase:limit 3 .
        bd:serviceParam mwapi:search ?searchTerm.
        bd:serviceParam mwapi:language "en".
        ?item wikibase:apiOutputItem mwapi:item.
        ?num wikibase:apiOrdinal true.
    }
    ?item (wdt:P279|wdt:P31) ?type
}
ORDER BY ?searchTerm ?num
```

This returns the following wikidata labels.

```
 wd:Q618079  --> related to electronics
 wd:Q4417999  --> related to graph theory (computer science)
 wd:Q60640547 --> related to scholary article
```

I would like to get the `wikidata labels` that are only related to computer science (i.e. `wd:Q4417999` in the above example).

In DBpedia I ran the below query to identify if a word is in `computer science`.

```
sparql.setQuery(" ASK { dbc:Network_analysis skos:broader{1,7} dbc:Computer_science } ")
```

Is it possible to do the same in wikidata (i.e. check if `computer science` is an ancestor of the given concept and returns only that wikidata label).

If there is a better solution than performing ancestoral search please do suggest me.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: by the way, your `ASK` query for DBpedia can't work.  `computer_science` is neither a URI nor a literal in its current form. I guess the prefix `dbc:` is missing here. And the URIs are always case-sensitive, it should be `dbc:Network_analysis`

Comment: `filter exists {?type wdt:279*/wdt:P361* wd:Q21198}`

Comment: @AKSW Thanks a lot. I updated my DBpedia query according to your comment. By the way, could you please tell me what is meant by `wdt:279*/wdt:P361*` property path? Is it possible to use a range of hops (e.g., {1,7}) in wikidata? I look forward to hearing from you. Thank you very much once again :)

Comment: Your query is still wrong. it has to be `dbc:Computer_science`

Comment: `wdt:279*/wdt:P361*` means zero or more steps via subclass relation followed by zero or more steps via `partOf` relation. Not sure, a feature like `{1,7}` isn'T standard syntax because it didn't made it to the final SPARQL 1.1 specs and is just an extension of the Virtuoso triple store. Indeed, you could try to do something like `:p/:p?/:p?/:p? ...` - and I never tried the Blazegraph feature with the lower/upper bound setting: https://wiki.blazegraph.com/wiki/index.php/PropertyPaths

Comment: @AKSW Thanks a lot for the details. Couldyou please tell me where I need to use this command `:p/:p?/:p?/:p?/:p?/:p?/:p?`. I will also look into Blazegraph as you have suggested. Looking forward to hearing from you. Thank you very much :)

Comment: it was just an example for a dummy property `:p` - indeed you have to use it in the property path with the property of your choice. I don't know your use-case not why you want to restrict something to a depth between `1 to 7`. if you want to compare DBpedia (aka Wikipedia category hierarchy) and Wikidata, then you have to understand that in the path I used there have been 2 different properties because it looks like classes are related via subclass and partof relation as you can see from https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q131476

Comment: @AKSW Thanks a lot for the details. They were very useful. Thank you very much once again :)

Comment: @AKSW When I run the query you mentioned above (`filter exists {?type wdt:279*/wdt:P361* wd:Q21198}`) for my real dataset I noted that `word2vec` is getting removed (even though it is a computer science term). Therefore, I thought that it would be great to get your feedback on that. Could you please let me know why that happens, and is there a way to resolve it? I look foward to hearing fro you. Thank you very much :)

Comment: honestly, it's too confusing right now. You're mixing up questions, comments and all the things. I don't know which final query you mean and I don't have the time to read again all the comments and questions. Either you provide always the full current query that does not work, or I can't help you. Sorry

Comment: and for "word2vec" you have to go the subclass and/or partOf hierarchy up. I never said that my answers are perfect nor complete because you always provided only parts of the details or part of the examples. So far, you know all the things like how to traverse the hierarchy up and how to filter out terms, just put it together. you should be able to make it with all the things I told you

Comment: @AKSW I am really sorry. Sure, I will mention my entire query next time when I ask a question. I am sorry :)

Comment: @AKSW I have attached my current query herewith in wikidata query editor: [URL](w.wiki/3jg)  Could you please kindly let me know how I can alter the `filter` in my query to retain nodes that go `the subclass and/or partOf hierarchy up`. I tried to do it as follows `filter exists {?type wdt:279*/wdt:P361*/(wdt:P279|wdt:P361)* wd:Q21198}`. However, my query got timeout. I look forward to hearing from you. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @AKSW Mentioned below is my full query `SELECT DISTINCT ?item {
VALUES ?searchTerm { "word2vec"}
SERVICE wikibase:mwapi {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:api "EntitySearch".
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:endpoint "www.wikidata.org".
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:limit 3 .
    bd:serviceParam mwapi:search ?searchTerm.
    bd:serviceParam mwapi:language "en".
    ?item wikibase:apiOutputItem mwapi:item.
    ?num wikibase:apiOrdinal true.
}
?item (wdt:P279|wdt:P31) ?type
filter exists {?type wdt:279*/wdt:P361* wd:Q21198}
}
ORDER BY ?searchTerm ?num` Thank you very much :)

Comment: there was I typo in my filter, it should be `wdt:P279`: `filter exists {?type wdt:P279*/wdt:P361* wd:Q21198}` - you should also try to read and understand comments from others to avoid such simple errors. As I said, I'm making many mistakes and none of my answers is supposed to be complete or perfect.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know in advance when `subClassOf` or `partOf` relation is used. And it clearly can be a mix of both.  The most complete filter would probably be `filter exists {?type (wdt:P279|wdt:P361)* wd:Q21198}` but it leads to a timeout. An alternative would be to follow only only one of the properties in the property path, or maybe a sequence but not the alternation. Now it's up to you, I guess all is said.

Comment: And please, finish your open questions now and provide the answer to each of them such they are marked as closed. For other things, open new questions and don't always ping me - that's necessary to avoid that other users do not always think it's only me who is asked. Ask a general public question

Comment: @AKSW Sure, thanks a lot and I am sorry. sure, I will also post answers for my questions. Thank you very much once again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sparql query mentioned below solved my issue.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item {
VALUES ?searchTerm { "network analysis"}
SERVICE wikibase:mwapi {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:api "EntitySearch".
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:endpoint "www.wikidata.org".
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:limit 3 .
    bd:serviceParam mwapi:search ?searchTerm.
    bd:serviceParam mwapi:language "en".
    ?item wikibase:apiOutputItem mwapi:item.
    ?num wikibase:apiOrdinal true.
}
?item (wdt:P279|wdt:P31) ?type
filter exists {?type wdt:P279*/wdt:P361* wd:Q21198}
}
ORDER BY ?searchTerm ?num
```